# Enterprise Architect, customize export of use case scenario steps

Tags: uml, use-case, enterprise-architect

when exporting to RTF i get the steps from my use case scenario steps as 1 textline 
: 1) some text 2) some other text 3) even other text..

I would like to have this text as a list instead of 1 long sentence with numbers in it. How can i achieve that? I tried to modify the RTF template but is still keeps 1 line in the export.

example

- some text
- some other text
- even other text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't exactly what you were after, but with [Enterprise Architects](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) [Structured Scenarios](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/modeling_fundamentals/structured_specification_tab.html) you can generate internal and external TestCases with the Test description having the format you requested.

When EA generates the test case it will also generate all the test steps for you (and the alternate steps as well), and place them in the Scenario tab in the testing dialog (Alt+3). Keep in mind you will need to have the Use Case selected to show the correct tests.

You can then run the RTF report over these tests and get the correct steps for the report.

I hope this helps